# Openvpn and port blocking

Tags: firewall, openvpn, port

I use openvpn on my desktop and all traffic goes through it. I blocked ports 443 and 80 FORWARD on the router. No processes are using ports 443 or 80 on my pc.

Because ports 80 and 443 are blocked even with openvpn I can't load any website. How is this possible?